# Quickest way to groupby for multiple variables/columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Bear with me on this, I'm not sure how well I'll be able to explain this problem. I have a dataframe `df`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"var1":["A","B","B","A","B","C","A","C"],"var2":["foo","bar","bar","foo","foo","foo","bar","foo"],
                   "var3":["apple","apple","peach","plum","pear","peach","plum","pear"],"actual":[13,2,14,6,8,4,12,9],
                   "expected":[11,4,9,4,12,0,10,14]})

print(df)

  var1 var2   var3  actual  expected
0    A  foo  apple      13        11
1    B  bar  apple       2         4
2    B  bar  peach      14         9
3    A  foo   plum       6         4
4    B  foo   pear       8        12
5    C  foo  peach       4         0
6    A  bar   plum      12        10
7    C  foo   pear       9        14
```

My overall goal is to go through the variables (`var1, var2, var3`) grouping each by the unique categories within the variable, and summing the actual and expected for each group.

For instance, when I group by `var1` I expect something like this

```py
df1=pd.DataFrame({"var1":["A","B","C"],"actual":[31,24,13],"expected":[25,25,14]})
print(df1)

  var1  actual  expected
0    A      31        25
1    B      24        25
2    C      13        14
```

`var2` this:

```py
df2=pd.DataFrame({"var2":["foo","bar"],"actual":[40,28],"expected":[41,23]})
print(df2)

  var2  actual  expected
0  foo      40        41
1  bar      28        23
```

and `var3` this:

```py
df3=pd.DataFrame({"var3":["apple","peach","plum","pear"],"actual":[15,18,18,17],"expected":[15,9,14,26]})
print(df3)
    var3  actual  expected
0  apple      15        15
1  peach      18         9
2   plum      18        14
3   pear      17        26
```

After this is created, I want to sum the absolute deviations for each group each groupby (and then sum those).

Essentially, something like this.

```py
print(abs(df1["actual"]-df1["expected"]).sum())
print(abs(df2["actual"]-df2["expected"]).sum())
print(abs(df3["actual"]-df3["expected"]).sum())

print(abs(df1["actual"]-df1["expected"]).sum()+abs(df2["actual"]-df2["expected"]).sum()+abs(df3["actual"]-df3["expected"]).sum())
```

which gives 8, 6, 22, 36 respectively.

The current way I do it is like so:

```py
variables = ["var1","var2","var3"]
expecteds = []
actuals = []
for var in variables:
    expecteds = np.append(expecteds, (df["expected"].groupby(df[var])).sum())
    actuals = np.append(actuals, (df["actual"].groupby(df[var])).sum())

print(np.sum(abs(expecteds-actuals)))
```

which gives 36.0.

The answer is correct, but I'm wondering if anyone sees a faster way to do this. I don't need output from intermediate steps, so as long as it outputs 36 it will work perfectly.

*For reference, on my computer this method runs:
`16.6 ms ± 959 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`*

I've never had to use Pandas on dataframes so big that I have to be conscious of runtime until now.

Comment: If you're calculating per each group, then summing each group, unless you want to double count overlaps (where there are differences between the var1/var2/var3 ), then does 36 make sense? Your absolute difference on the raw table is only 26...

Comment: @JonClements It doesn't make sense intuitively, but for the project I'm working on it's the preferable way to look at it. But yes, it does have a lot of overlap and double counting.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches that will be faster than what you do now, although there is nothing wrong with your approach, it seems to work fine.

---

#### `set_index` + `concat` + `sum`

```
u = df.set_index(['var1', 'var2', 'var3'])

f = pd.concat([u.sum(level=n) for n in range(u.index.nlevels)], ignore_index=True)

f['actual'].sub(f['expected']).abs().sum()
```

```
36
```

---

#### `melt` + `groupby` + `sum`

```
um = df.melt(['actual', 'expected']).groupby('value')[['actual', 'expected']].sum()

um['actual'].sub(um['expected']).abs().sum()
```

```
36
```

Comment: Both of these options worked great on my trial dataframe (about 20% quicker than original), but when I tried to apply it to the entire dataset (with over 300,000 rows and 200+ groupby statements) it took 5x longer than my original way. In theory it seemed great though (perhaps I implemented it wrong? I'll keep trying).

Comment: This solution scales based on a different metric than your solution, on your data your solution may work best.  I'm sure you implemented it right, it might just not be the right approach for your data.

Comment: I appreciate the help anyways! Thanks

Comment: @Paulfryy if you have time - I'd be curious to see how pivot_table compares here... by the sounds of it though (and the number of columns you have) - I'm not feeling overly optimistic now :)

Comment: @JonClements - just implemented it into my real code and it's not too bad! It took a fair bit longer than the original code on the test dataframe, but when brought into my real code it took ~2x as long (1.4 sec avg versus 3 sec avg). Considering the size of the pivot table created I think that's relatively good

Comment: @Paulfryy thanks very much for doing that! Not quite as bad as I'd expected (given the timings on this one) but far from as good as I'd like it to be... but oh well... think this is one of those I'll make a note of - intuitively it seems like there must be a more efficient way of doing this, but it eludes me right now :)

Comment: @user3483203 in the 2nd option (with `melt`), what is the variable 'value'? It is not a column name in the df. Is it something that get's created with `melt`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the most efficient, or even more efficient at all, but you can at least shorten the amount of code you have to write by taking advantage of [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

```
s = 0
for var in ('var1','var2','var3'):
    s = s + df.groupby(var).sum().apply(lambda row: np.abs(row['actual']-row['expected']), axis=1).sum()
```

The main idea here is to use apply along axis=1, which returns individual rows. Then besides that, all of the logic is the same.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you. The selection of data & grouping (all done with pandas methods) is different but the dataframe & the print statements are same that you put in. This also gives the output 8,6,22 & 36.

Regarding the speed, you will have to check on your computer.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"var1":["A","B","B","A","B","C","A","C"],"var2":  ["foo","bar","bar","foo","foo","foo","bar","foo"],
               "var3":["apple","apple","peach","plum","pear","peach","plum","pear"],"actual":[13,2,14,6,8,4,12,9],
               "expected":[11,4,9,4,12,0,10,14]})
df1=df[['var1','actual','expected']]
df2=df[['var2','actual','expected']]
df3=df[['var3','actual','expected']]
df1=df1.groupby('var1').sum()
df2=df2.groupby('var2').sum()
df3=df3.groupby('var3').sum()

print(abs(df1["actual"]-df1["expected"]).sum())
print(abs(df2["actual"]-df2["expected"]).sum())
print(abs(df3["actual"]-df3["expected"]).sum())

print(abs(df1["actual"]-df1["expected"]).sum()+abs(df2["actual"]- df2["expected"]).sum()+abs(df3["actual"]-df3["expected"]).sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `pivot_table` creating an summary table to work with.

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(columns=['var1', 'var2', 'var3'])
diff = df2['actual'] - df2['expected']
```

That gives you:

```
var1  var2  var3 
A     bar   plum     2
      foo   apple    2
            plum     2
B     bar   apple   -2
            peach    5
      foo   pear    -4
C     foo   peach    4
            pear    -5
```

You can then take the absolute sums of the sum of each level, eg:

```
total = sum(diff.sum(level=n).abs().sum() for n in range(diff.index.nlevels))
```

Which gives you 36.